# Gain effects of `JsonConstructor` without editing class

Tags: c#, json.net

I have some classes with read only properties and constructors, e.g:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Foo { get; }
    public bool Bar { get; }
    public MyClass(string foo);
    public MyClass(string foo, bool bar);
}
```

Which will serialize but `DeserializeObject` will fail.

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException : Unable to find a constructor to use for type MyClass. A class should either have a default constructor, one constructor with arguments or a constructor marked with the JsonConstructor attribute. Path '...', line 1, position 1

Adding `JsonConstructor` attribute will work, but sometimes I don't control the types source code. Can I tell the converter to act as if the attribute was there some other way?

Ideally without doing every parameter manually in a `JsonConverter.ReadJson` for each type in question.

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but as a workaround - nothing is forcing you to deserialize to that specific type. You might as well deserialize to your own type, or even an anonymous type, and then map the results to the actual target type. Sure, that will require writing some code, but so will a custom json converter...

Comment: Well, that is pretty similar to doing each parameter for each type... I could probably write a generic solution via reflection (I assume what Json.Net does internally anyway). But if can say  "use this constructor `typeA, typeB`" or "pretend it had this attribute x on member y" would rather not reinvent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Made a bit research and it looks like you can use custom `JsonContractResolver` during deserialization, which will provide serializer with correct object creator.
So, deserialization looks like:

```js
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new MyContractResolver() };
var myClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>("{ \"Foo\": \"Hello\", \"Bar\": true }", settings);
```

And `MyContractResolver` is:

```js
public class MyContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public override JsonContract ResolveContract(Type type)
    {
        var contract = base.ResolveContract(type);
        if (type == typeof(MyClass) && contract is JsonObjectContract objectContract)
        {
            objectContract.OverrideCreator = (args) => new MyClass((string)args[0], (bool)args[1]);
            var overrideConstructor = typeof(MyClass).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(string), typeof(bool) });
            foreach (var param in CreateConstructorParameters(overrideConstructor, objectContract.Properties))
                objectContract.CreatorParameters.Add(param);
        }
        return contract;
    }
}
```

Of course, that's very schematic and `JsonSerializer` attribute is far more convinient to use. However, if you have legacy classes, this may help.

Idea is that when `Serializer` fills `JsonContract` for your type - let default contract resolver build it and then inject constructor that you actually need to call in `OverrideCreator` property of contract, and description of its arguments in `CreatorParameters`.

Comment: Seems the bet approach. Looked around in that code, there is an overridable `CreateObjectContract`. It actually uses `GetAttributeConstructor` to find the attribute but that it seems is not overridable, seems `DefaultContractResolver` handles a bunch of the attributes.